# Is there a Roslyn analyzer for validating OpenAPI response type, function signature return value and response content type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openapi, .net-5

In a .Net 5.0 web API project, I have enabled OpenAPI analyzers in my csproj file with this element

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <IncludeOpenAPIAnalyzers>true</IncludeOpenAPIAnalyzers>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In my controller, if I have this code

```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(bool), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public ActionResult<int> MyFunction()
{
    return Ok("abc");
}
```

then, I don't get any warnings that the `ProducesResponseTypeAttribute`'s return type *`bool`* doesn't match the function signature's `ActionResult` generic type *`int`*.

I also don't get any compilation errors even though `OK(...)` contains a `string` type instead of an `int` type.

Is there a Roslyn analyzer that can detect this type of coding error?